# Streaming video to PCIE slot

Tags: c, linux, video-streaming, fpga, pci

I'd like to be able to stream video from a camera attached to my computer directly to an FPGA I have attached to my computer via PCIE.

I don't mind using a high level language like javascript or C# to do this (as those are the langauges I know have video streaming abilities), but I recognize that in order to get to that level of hardware, I may have to use C (which I know pretty well).

I just wondered if there is a certain route I'll have to go in order to accomplish this, like installing Linux (it's a windows 7 computer), or using a specific language, or if there is a library out there that does this already.

Thanks!

Comment: This one: http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=138&No=501&PartNo=4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it sounds to me you'll need to write a kernel driver for your hardware.

This means you'll need to learn kernel development.  For Windows, you need the WDK, Windows Driver Kit.

I'm not familar with Linux kernel development.

Comment: ugh, that sounds awful haha.  Thank you though.

Comment: Does your hardware come with a library / API you can use to access the data?

Comment: Must the new driver be used with video4linux ?

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way of doing this would probably be to do it through a DMA channel, but if it's just a standard video stream, you should be able to cope with the much simpler programmed I/O (PIO), which should give you up to 30MB/s when writing over a PCIe x1 link if done correctly - although this will use more processor resources on your PC than DMA.

I worked on interfacing an FPGA to a PC through PCI express during a preproject to my master's thesis - a pdf version can be found here: http://loejer.dk/files/FORK,%20pdf.zip (the journal2-5 pdf's are probably those of most interest)

It covers the FPGA side (using a Xilinx Spartan3, but it's basically the same with a Spartan6T), and both Windows (XP) and Linux drivers also.